# Spark SQL: Number of partitions being generated seems weird

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, task

I have a very simple Hive table with the below structure.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1(
col1 STRING,
col2 STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION 's3://path/';
```

The directory this table is being pointed to has just ONE file of size 51 KB.

From the pyspark shell (with all default values):

```
df = sparksession.sql("SELECT * from table1")
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

The number of partitions being returned is weird. Sometimes it returned 64 and sometimes 81.

My expectation was to see 1 or 2 partitions utmost. Any thoughts on why I see that many partitions?

Thanks.

Comment: Most of them would be possibly empty. Just try to repartitions the file by specifying the number of partitions.

Comment: Actually there are around 4000 rows in the table and i noticed that approx 50 rows were present in each partition.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that number of partitions returned sometimes it returned 64 and sometimes 81 because its up to the spark that in how many partitions it want to store the data even if you use the repartition command then also its a request to the spark to shuffle the data into given re partitions if spark thinks its not possible then it will take the decision by itself and store the data in random number of partitions.

Hope this explanation solves your query.

Comment: Thanks Ankit, but it still does not. Why does a simple 51 KB file results in 64/81 partitions? That is still open.